# Laravel 5.5. queue push

Tags: php, laravel, queue

I have upgraded my app from Laravel 4.2 to 5.5 and I am getting issues with the queue.

```
public function saved(Model $review)
{
    if (App::runningInConsole()) {
        return;
    }

    $data = [
        'review' => serialize($review),
        'action' => self::ACTION_SAVE
    ];
    Queue::push(new UpdateReviewSummaryQueue, $data);
}
```

When I run this on model save, I am getting an error that the `UpdateReviewSummaryQueue` class does not exist. I've ran `composer dump-autoload` and namespacing seems to be fine. Are there any other issues I might look into?

I've also added

```
use SerializesModels;
```

as Laravel upgrade guide suggested

Comment: Have you added the statement use \UpdateReviewSummaryQueue at top

Comment: is `Queue::push` exist in laravel 5.5 ? or it changed to `dispatch` ? many changes done in this interval `4.2 to 5.5`

Comment: can you provide the full error message ... Laravel uses namespaces everywhere ... side note, you dont need to serialize a model yourself, the jobs can serialize the models themselves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was actually in this line:

```
Queue::push(new UpdateReviewSummaryQueue, $data);
```

Changing it to this made it work:

```
Queue::push(UpdateReviewSummaryQueue::class, $data);
```

Answer (score 0):

In laravel 5.5 you now `dispatch` jobs rather than `push`. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/queues#dispatching-jobs for full documentation. 
Try :

```
dispatch((new UpdateReviewSummaryQueue($data));
```